# Run PHP in memory

Tags: php, google-app-engine

As I can't write file on the GAE server, is there a way that I can directly run PHP code in memory without the help of a php file. 
**BTW, I was using Quercus to run PHP in GAE.**
You can refer to the link: http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2009/run-php-on-the-google-app-engine/
Thank you so much.

Comment: What does this have to do with not being able to write files on App Engine? Why are you trying to execute PHP code determined at runtime?

Comment: hi Nick, I was getting PHP code from POST and I will send the result back so I was wondering how to run the PHP code. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) from PHP to execute a string of PHP code without saving it to a file.

For example:

```
eval('echo hi;'); // this echoes "hi"
```

Comment: thx lunixbochs, I was thinking of that as well, but I need to use http to post my PHP code to the file, I have tried, works fine locally but not on GAE. :(

Comment: GAE might have security features to prevent code injection. try running eval built into your code, and try POSTing base64-encoded PHP

Comment: thx again lunixbochs, the problem happens during POSTing the PHP code, I was using HTTPConnection utf to post it, but it seems like I can get results sometimes and sometimes will get nothing. :(

Answer (score 2):

You can upload the file, you just can't create one using code

So you can upload the PHP files you want *with* the Quercus stuff, and access the files, but the Python/PHP/Java code being run on the server cannot create files

I don't really see why you want to use a dynamic PHP file...

Comment: hi Jasper, I just want to run PHP code in GAE server and get result. if I can run PHP code in memory directly, I don't need to create file. :)